# Getting a level of an ALV tree node?

Tags: treeview, abap, alv

I created an ALV TREE report, using cl_gui_alv_tree, that has 3 levels. I'm also implementing an event handler for when he double clicks a node.

My problem is that I want to take some actions only when he double clicks a node that is a root node. The event 'node_double_click' gives a node_key, but that's the index of the displayed table. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The node ID is not an index, it's the ID you assigned to the node when adding it to the tree.

If possible, I'd suggest switching to `CL_SALV_TREE` - not only because it is [documented](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp2004/helpdata/en/5e/88d440e14f8431e10000000a1550b0/frameset.htm)
and supported by SAP, but also because it comes with some query methods that are quite handy. These methods are [documented as well](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp2004/helpdata/en/f1/e4eb40c4f8712ae10000000a155106/frameset.htm). You can use, for example, `GET_NODE` to retrieve a node by its ID and then use `GET_PARENT` to check whether the node in question is a top-level node or has a parent node it is attached to.

Answer (score 1):

I created a pattern for myself, which i am using.

```
        lv_parent1 = node_key.

    while lv_parent1 ne go_Main_tree->C_VIRTUAL_ROOT_NODE.
      CALL METHOD go_main_tree->get_parent
        EXPORTING
          i_node_key        = lv_parent1
        IMPORTING
          e_parent_node_key = lv_parent1.

         lv_hierlevel   = lv_hierlevel + 1 .

     ENDWHILE.

    if lv_hierlevel > 2.
        “ do what You want to do
    endif.
```